# How to remove the last character in a string variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have subject codes where the last digit of the code is the session number.
Using substring I can create a new session number variable, however the session number still needs to be removed from the original subject code. (AN11GR1 should become AN11GR)

Here is a reproducible example with a solution:

```
structure(list(subject = c("AN11GR1", "AN11GR2", "BR13ST1", "BR13ST2"
), target = c("m_ve", "k_ck", "m_ve", "k_ck"), corrAns = c("o", 
"i", "o", "i"), RT = c(2.9254148, 1.7154148, 2.6454148, 1.9254148
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)) -> myData

myData$session <- substring(myData$subject, nchar(myData$subject))
myData$subject <- substring(myData$subject, 1, nchar(myData$subject)-1)

myData <- subset(myData, select = c(subject, session, RT))
myData
```

Ideas on how to remove the last character in a concise and convenient way? (For the most concise solution see akrun's comment.)

Comment: An option is `myData %>% tidyr::extract(subject, into = c("subject", "session"), "(.*)(.)$", convert = TRUE)` (assuming your question is about making the code concise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line to your code. Using `substring` and `nchar` you could define to remove the last character:

```
myData$subject <- substring(myData$subject, 1, nchar(myData$subject)-1)
myData
```

```
  subject session       RT
1  AN11GR       1 2.925415
2  AN11GR       2 1.715415
3  BR13ST       1 2.645415
4  BR13ST       2 1.925415
```